# How can I plot these three equations?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, parametric-functions

There are 3 parametric equations given I have to plot the sphere. I tried with `ParametricPlot3D`, but it does not show any graph. Then, I also tried using `Sphereplot3D` and found the same error
[image: mathma2.jpg]

I tried this but does not work.

[image: mathma.jpg]

Comment: From Wolfram MathWorld ([link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html)), use equations 4,5,6 as a reference. Use `Sin` and `Cos` as these are case sensitive.

Comment: @Syed I don't see any disagreement with the link you provided, other than in the OP $r$ is set to one. Am I missing anything?

Comment: I provided this link "as a reference" for the benefit of future visitors to the page.

Comment: @Syed oh, I see. thanks for breaking it down for me, because I thought I  was missing some detail :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

"13.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"
```

**Explanation:** you had a syntax error. Built-in functions should be capitalized. Instead of `sin`, it should have been `Sin`. Observe the different colors between them.

---

- Using [`ParametricPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html)

The first approach is:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 {Cos[x] Sin[y], Sin[x] Sin[y], Cos[y]},
 {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, Pi},
 Boxed -> False,
 Axes -> False
 ]
```

[image: sphere]

---

- Using [`SphericalPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SphericalPlot3D.html)

We can also do:

```
SphericalPlot3D[1, θ, φ]
```

[image: sphereagain]

---

This is just for fun, hopefully it will get you excited with the functionality as well.

- Using [`ContourPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html)

This is in case you wanted to use the equation form in terms of the $x,y,z$ coordinates. We'll do an animation just to have some fun.

The animation is

[image: animation]

Below, I am providing the code. It's pretty simple, but maybe it will give you enough to go and read the documentation carefully.

Please note, that in order to execute it as I have it written you need to save your notebook somewhere and then run the commands.

```
sphere = Animate[
  ContourPlot3D[
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == rr,
   {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
   Axes -> False,
   Boxed -> False,
   Mesh -> Full,
   MeshStyle -> {Dashed, Thick}
   ],
  {rr, .25, 2},
  AnimationRate -> .5,
  AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward]
```

The following will create a .gif file wherever it is that you have saved your notebook.

```
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]
Export["sphere3d.gif", sphere]
```

Have fun :-)